# Is the Canon EF 50mm f/2.5 Compact Macro compatible with the Canon 6D body?

Tags: canon, canon-6d, canon-ef

I am planning to buy this lens for my 6D. Will they match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All EF lenses** manufactured since 1987 will work on **all EF mount EOS SLR cameras** made by Canon since 1987 when the EOS system was introduced.

This includes **all film EOS SLR cameras** and **all digital EOS SLR cameras** including **all DSLR models with full frame, APS-H, and APS-C size sensors**.

EF-S lenses will only work on EOS DSLR cameras with APS-C sized sensors.

EF-M lenses are designed specifically for the EF-M mount used by EOS M cameras (none of which are SLR cameras) and are not compatible with Canon SLR film cameras and DSLR camera models.